# Can endless async workflow overflow stack

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Suppose we have this potentially endless workflow:

```
let workAsync i = async { 
    printfn "Working... %A" i
    if i > 3 then
        failwith "errg"
    elif i = -1000 then // ensure work is async
        do! Async.Sleep 0
    return i+1
}

let workflow =
    async {
        let mutable i = 0
        while true do           // I can't quit you!
            let! j = workAsync i
            i <- j
            //do! Async.Sleep 0 // This is important?
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

If you run this, we get the expected exception.  **Notice how the stacktrace has grown.**  This can be made larger.

```
Working... 0
Working... 1
Working... 2
Working... 3
Working... 4
> System.Exception: errg
  at FSI_0017.workAsync@155-45.Invoke(Unit unitVar) in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 157
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.CallThenInvoke[T,TResult](AsyncActivation`1 ctxt, TResult result1, FSharpFunc`2 part2)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at FSI_0017.workAsync@158-47.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt) in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 158
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at FSI_0017.workAsync@158-47.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt) in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 158
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at FSI_0017.workAsync@158-47.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt) in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 158
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at FSI_0017.workAsync@158-47.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt) in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 158
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.unitAsync@607.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.Execute(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncResult`1.Commit()
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronouslyInAnotherThread[a](CancellationToken token, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronously[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T](FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout, FSharpOption`1 cancellationToken)
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0017>.$FSI_0017.main@() in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 161
```

BUT if we uncomment the Async.Sleep line, the stack does not grow:

```
Working... 0
Working... 1
Working... 2
Working... 3
Working... 4
> System.Exception: errg
   at FSI_0002.workAsync@155.Invoke(Unit unitVar) in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 157
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.CallThenInvoke[T,TResult](AsyncActivation`1 ctxt, TResult result1, FSharpFunc`2 part2)
   at FSI_0002.workflow@167-5.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt) in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 167
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.Execute(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncResult`1.Commit()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronouslyInAnotherThread[a](CancellationToken token, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronously[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T](FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout, FSharpOption`1 cancellationToken)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002.main@() in C:\work\website_tq\tqit7\fs\Scripts\fsi_basic.fsx:line 161
```

*** Modified: *** Changed `workAsync` to ensure the async'nicity isn't optimized away.

Comment: It might also differ depending on if you compile and link this code vs. running it in FSI. Maybe.

Comment: Yeah, this was run in FSI, but it also happens in my production code.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because there is nothing actually async in your workflow when `Sleep` is commented out.

Everything is completely synchronous, but because it's encoded in the `async` computation expression, it becomes weirdly nested. See, every `let!` line actually calls whatever is on the right side (in your example - `workAsync`) and passes it a callback that needs to be called once the asynchronous part is done. The callback contains the rest of the code - a continuation starting right after the `let!` line. The compiler performs clever transformations on the code to make it look all nice and linear, when in reality it's a series of callbacks.

However, since `workAsync` is not actually asynchronous, it just calls the callback right away, and the callback turns around and calls the next iteration of `workAsync`, and so on. And so your stack grows.

But wait! It actually shouldn't grow after all. Invocation of the callback is the last call in `workAsync` - also known as "tail call", - and both .NETCore and .NET Framework do eliminate those (and indeed: on my machine I cannot reproduce your result). The only speculation I can offer is that you must be running this on Mono, which doesn't always eliminate tail calls.

If you uncomment `Sleep`, however, then it becomes the breaking point. `Sleep` is *actually* asynchronous, which means that it schedules the callback to be executed on a new thread after a timeout. That execution starts from scratch, with a fresh stack, and so the stack doesn't grow, even when tail calls are not eliminated.

**So to answer your original question:** no, an endless async computation cannot overflow stack, except when it's not actually async and runs on Mono.

Comment: I'm not running this in mono but it is in FSI. It's weird that you can't reproduce it...

Comment: 1. FSI can be running on mono. Please check. 2. How did you change `workAsync`?

Comment: I modified the question above with the new workAsync. I'm running on windows & the issue also appears in production code (.NET Framework 4.6.1 & neither mono nor FSI)

Comment: Your mortified `workAsync` is still not actually asynchronous: it never actually calls `Sleep`, so the continuation never gets scheduled on a different thread. Try inserting the `Sleep` call somewhere it will actually happen, like at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by "actually" async.  Of course, putting a Sleep does fix the issue.  Then again, my production code actual has async ops...

Comment: Then I suggest you create a repro that contains async operations, based on your production code.